# Attempting to mute sound on YouTube video playlist autoplay

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, youtube, flash

I'm trying to embed a YouTube playlist on a site and have it autoplay with the sound muted. I found this code to do that:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="ytapiplayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
ytplayer.playVideo();
ytplayer.mute();
}
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/mOLp4doE51Q&list=PL86C090F73345FED6&feature=plpp_play_all?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&allowFullScreen=true&version=3&loop=1&autohide=1",
"ytapiplayer", "100%", "380", "8", null, null, params, atts)
</script>
```

It is a WordPress site and when I entered that code it just automatically deleted all of the widgets on the sidebar and header that were iFrames/ads. I put the code in the widget that normally has the video code in it and didn't touch the other widgets but when I reloaded it there were all gone and I had to rebuild them all (luckily from a backup).

On top of it, the videos didn't even load.

I'm assuming this code is somehow targeting iFrames and then running some code on them? Can somebody help me decipher this problem before I give it another go? I'm not great with Javascript and am trying to find some answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the above codes works just fine. The copy and paste from the website I was looking at had parentheses from a foreign keyboard that weren't recognized when I pasted them.

I'm still at a loss of why it would break all the iframes and automatically delete them but the solution is from changing out the parentheses.